# In Spring Boot 2, how do I construct a curl request to POST (create) an entity when it has foreign keys?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, curl, post, spring-restcontroller

I'm using Spring Boot 2, Java 11, and PostGres 10.  I have the following entity.  Notice it has a couple of many-to-one foreign key constraints ...

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cards")
public class Card {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Occasion occasion;
    
    @Lob
    private byte[] image;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private User author;
}
```

I have built the following controller for allowing creating and editing of that entity ...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/card")
public class CardController {

    @Autowired
    private CardService cardService;
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Card> read(@PathVariable("id") UUID id) {
        Card foundCard = cardService.findById(id);
        if (foundCard == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(foundCard);
        }
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@RequestBody Card card) {
        cardService.save(card);
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Card> update(@RequestBody Card card, @PathVariable UUID id) {
        final Card updatedCard = cardService.update(id, card);
        if (updatedCard == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedCard);
        }
    }
    
}
```

How do I construct a curl request that will submit an entity to my endpoint?  I have tried the below ...

```
curl -v --header "Content-type: application/json" --data '{"occasion_id": "a989055a-b4f4-11ea-a1d1-6a0000c30600", "author_id": "8cfd5756-00c0-478e-a9b5-2ce23e78ea70", "image": "Tom"}' --request POST "http://localhost:8080/api/card"
```

But this results in a 400 error with the message ...

```
{"timestamp":"2020-06-23T02:00:53.893+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/api/card"}
```

Is it possible to adjust my Java code or curl request such that I'm able to successfully create my entity?

Comment: Where is `occasion`, `image` and `author` objects in your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -v --header "Content-type: application/json" \
--data '{"occasion": {"id": "a989055a-b4f4-11ea-a1d1-6a0000c30600"}, "author": {"id": "8cfd5756-00c0-478e-a9b5-2ce23e78ea70"}, "image": "<base64 encoded image>"}' \
--request POST "http://localhost:8080/api/card"
```

Here is formatted JSON of `Card`:

```
{
  "id": "...",
  "occasion": {
    "id": "...",
    ...
  },
  "image": <base64 encoded image>,
  "author": {
    "id": "...",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try your JSON, I get the same error, '{"timestamp":"2020-06-23T15:11:54.355+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/api/card"}'

Comment: Excuse me, I had not submitted the image parameter as a base64-encoded string and this was the cause of my previous error.  Everything else works fine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You CURL should be

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/card' \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "occasion": {
    "id": "a989055a-b4f4-11ea-a1d1-6a0000c30600"
  },
  "author": {
    "id": "8cfd5756-00c0-478e-a9b5-2ce23e78ea70"
  },
  "image": "Tom"
}'
```

You should have fields called `id` inside both the objects.

Comment: Sadly, using your CURL request results in a "{"timestamp":"2020-06-23T15:13:10.275+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/api/card"}" error.

Comment: Can you provide Occasion and User class in answer ?